# Perl dancer and Template Toolkit: Including template within template

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I am trying to INCLUDE a template within a template, like so:

parent.tt

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
    [% INCLUDE my_sidebar]
    </div><!--/span-->
   </div>
```

my_sidebar.tt exists in same folder as parent.tt (/myapp/views)

I have made the following changes to config.yml:
With ABSOLUTE

```
template: "template_toolkit"
engines:
   template_toolkit:
     encoding:  'utf8'
     start_tag: '[%'
     end_tag:   '%]'
     ABSOLUTE : 1
```

parent.tt contains:

```
[% INCLUDE /myapps/views/my_sidebar %]
```

With RELATIVE

```
template: "template_toolkit"
engines:
   template_toolkit:
     encoding:  'utf8'
     start_tag: '[%'
     end_tag:   '%]'
     RELATIVE : 1
     INCLUDE_PATH: /myapps/views
```

parent.tt contains:

```
[% INCLUDE my_sidebar %]
```

But in both cases, I get the following error:

```
core - template - file error - my_sidebar: not found at /.../csm/64-bit/cpan/5.16.1-2012.09/lib/Dancer/Template/Abstract.pm line 90.
```

Comment: try this `[% INCLUDE 'my_sidebar.tt' %]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the full filename - `my_sidebar.tt` - in your `INCLUDE`.  Dancer automatically appends a configurable extension (`.tt` by default) to the name of the main template, but TT doesn't know about that setting.